# Data won't load into templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I am using the code below to try and load a collection of books into an HTML template.

The data results do show up in my console, but I can't figure out why they are not showing up in my HTML templates.

I start off on a landing page and create the views below with this call:

var sv = new BookSearchView();

Where BookSearchView.js is the code below:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'jquery', 'text!BookSearchResults.html', 'text!Book.html', 'jquery-ui'],

function (_, Backbone, $, tmplBooks, tmplBook) {
'use strict';

//book model
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/search'
});

//book collection with URL to web query [this part works fine]
var BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book,
    url: '/api/search/fantasy'   //this loads a JSON string of fantasy books

});

//create my book collection
var Books = new BookCollection();
Books.fetch().done(function() {
});

 //main view
 return Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#search_container',
    className: 'Books',
    template: _.template(tmplBooks, null, { variable: 's' }),

    initialize: function () {
        this.BookCollection = Books;
    },

    render: function () {
        //loop through my book collection
        this.BookCollection.each(function(e) {
            this.renderBook(e);
        }, this);

    return this;
    }

        //render each book in the collection
    renderBook: function (e) {
        var self = this;
        var bookView = new BookView({
            model: e,
            parent: self,
        });
        this.$('#book_container').append(bookView.render().$el);
        console.log('Book view: ', bookView);  //I can see the data in my console!
    }

});

//book view
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'Book',
    template: _.template(tmplBook),

    initialize: function (args) {
        this.parent = args.parent;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});


});

<!--tmplBooks = BookSearchResults.html = search results template-->
<div id="book_container">
    <div class="Books">
        Search Results:
    </div>
</div>

<!--tmplBook = Book.html = individual book template-->
<div class="Book"></div>
```

Comment: You code is not well formatted, please fix it. Definition of `BookView` is inside of main view.

Comment: @VahanVardanyan thanks, good catch, sometimes copying and pasting code in here can be a pain.

Comment: What is printed in console?

Comment: A row for each book that is found, so it looks like a bunch of: book view: Object { cid="view117", model={...}, $el={...}, more...}

Comment: In main view's render function you are iterate over `BookCollection` - is it right? Or you need to iterate over the collection's instance?

Comment: In my main views initialize, I set this.BookCollection = Books; which is the collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66786/discussion-between-vahan-vardanyan-and-999cm999).

Comment: Are you waiting for the `fetch` to finish before you try to render the collection?

Comment: @muistooshort I don't think it's that, because I can see the data written out in the console...I'm just having trouble binding it to my html template

Comment: The console holds a live reference so what you see in the console isn't always what was there when you called `console.log`. `console.log(collection.toJSON())` will give you a proper snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but it seems that in your template you are passing the model.toJSON object but there is no variable in template to consume this value or render it. 
So each time the templete will be returning `"<div class="Book"></div>"` which will show nothing on html page.